# SEO and the Iframe srcDoc attribute

Tags: seo, html5, iframe

For a project I'm working on we're relying on `<iframe>`'s to display encapsulated content, but we're concerned about SEO.

My question is, how does Google/Bing view srcDoc content? Is it associated with the parent frame or with the iframe itself? What if the `<iframe>` has no `src` attribute?

Any help/links would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google means, it does its best to correctly recognize the content in `iframes`, while `iframes` are indeed violation against w3c, because `iframes` establish situation, where one url could get more then one head (one head of the site, and other head of the `iframe src` site).

My strong recommendation, if you make use of `iframe`, do explicit control of the `iframe` content:

- if you want `iframe` content is indexed, don't use `<head></head>` on the `iframe src` page - just put the content in it.
- if you don't want `iframe` content is indexed - use `<head><meta name="robots" content="noindex" /></head>` on the `iframe src` page. To close `iframe src` pages with `robots.txt` doesn't help, because `iframe src` pages are linked.